# session set inside function change after return

Tags: php, function, session, return

I've a really weird thing happening that I'm not able to reproduce out of my script but still if anyone has any idea how to solve this.
So I'm adding a token to a script to avoid double form submission.
I've got a pretty simple function that sets the session and returns the token:

```
function generate_token() {
  $token = sha1(mt_rand());
  $_SESSION['token'] = array($token => 1);
  print_r($_SESSION);
  return $token;
}
```

the print_r here shows this (exactly as it should):

```
Array
(
    [token] => Array
    (
        [1a1c5cbdbe9d85dcb0b55a712ff8bf187ae795cb] => 1
    )
)
```

and I call the script like so (nothing fancy)

```
$token = generate_token();
```

but if I print_r just after that outside the function, I get this

```
Array
(
    [token] => 1a1c5cbdbe9d85dcb0b55a712ff8bf187ae795cb
)
```

and if instead of

```
$token = generate_token();
```

I just call

```
generate_token();
```

it work like it should.

I've tried it out of my script in a test page and nothing weird happen. 
I can show you the rest of my code if needeed, but around this, it's only generating html.
as someone seen that before?
it's hurt my brain so any help will be appreciated.
Cheers

**EDIT:**

As requested, I put the full code here , the weirdness is happening around line 304.
here I've put the function which is normally called from an include which not change anything in my case. (the code is cut at the end due to SO character number limitations)

```
<?php
    require('includes/application_top.php');
    require('includes/functions/scrambled_order_num.php');    
      $quantity_left = isset($_POST['labels_qty']) ? $_POST['labels_qty']: 1;
      if (isset($_SESSION['quantity_needed']))  {
        $quantity_left = $_SESSION['quantity_needed'];
        unset($_SESSION['quantity_needed']);
      }
      $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
      $order_id = isset($_GET['order_id']) ? tep_db_input($_GET['order_id']) : '';
      $order_num = isset($_POST['order_num']) ? tep_db_input(trim($_POST['order_num'])) : '';
      $weight = isset($_POST['weight']) ? tep_db_input($_POST['weight']) : '';
      $label_type = isset($_POST['label_type']) ? tep_db_input($_POST['label_type']) : '';
      $CN23 = isset($_POST['CN23']) ? $_POST['CN23'] : '';
      $addressee = isset($_POST['addressee']) ? $_POST['addressee'] : '';
      $comments = isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : '';
      // update products infos
      if (!empty($CN23)) {
        foreach($CN23 as $pID => $values) {
          if (is_numeric($pID)) {
            $qry = "UPDATE products
                       SET origin_country_id = '" . (int)$values['originCountry'] . "'
                     WHERE products_id = '" . (int)$pID . "'";
            tep_db_query($qry);
            $qry = "UPDATE products_stock_location
                       SET weight = '" . $values['weight'] . "'
                     WHERE products_id = '" . (int)$pID . "'";
            tep_db_query($qry);
          }
        }
      }
      if (isset($_POST['deposit_date']) && empty($_POST['deposit_date'])) {
        $today = new DateTime();
        $deposit_date = $today->format("Y-m-d");
      } else if (isset($_POST['deposit_date'])) {
        $format = "d/m/Y";
        $date_object = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, tep_db_input($_POST['deposit_date']));
        $deposit_date = $date_object->format("Y-m-d");
      }
      switch ($action) {
        case 'get_infos':
          if (empty($order_id)){
            $order_id = derandomise_order_num($order_num);
          }
          // check actual shipping status
          $qry = "SELECT o.shipping_status, o.is_partial, o.orders_language, o.shipping_method
                    FROM orders AS o
                   WHERE o.orders_id = '" . $order_id . "'";
          $status_query = tep_db_query($qry);
          $status = tep_db_fetch_array($status_query);

          if ($status['shipping_status'] == SHIPPING_STATUS_READY_TO_SHIP) {
            $messageStack->add_session(TEXT_NOT_READY_TO_SHIP);
            tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHIPPING_LABEL));
          }
          if ($status['shipping_method'] == 'Chronopost') {
            $messageStack->add_session('chronopost');
            tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHIPPING_LABEL));
          }
        case 'get_label':
        case 'relai_lookup':
          $qry = "SELECT shipping_method
                    FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS . "
                   WHERE orders_id = "  . $order_id;
          $shipping_query = tep_db_query($qry);
          $shipping_result = tep_db_fetch_array($shipping_query);
          if ($shipping_result['shipping_method'] == 'Colissimo' || $shipping_result['shipping_method'] == 'So Colissimo' || $shipping_result['shipping_method'] == 'Colissimo free') {
            $module = 'socolissimo';
          } else if ($shipping_result['shipping_method'] == 'Chronopost') {
            $module = 'chronopost';
          }
          include_once(DIR_FS_CATALOG_MODULES . 'shipping/' . $module . ".php");
          $shipping = new $module;
          break;
          default:
          break;
        }
        if ($action == "relai_lookup") {
          $relai_id = $_POST['relai_id'];
          echo json_encode($shipping->get_relais_by_id($relai_id));
          die();
        }

        if ($action == 'get_label' ) {
          if (is_valid_token($_POST['token'])) {
            $label = $shipping->get_label( $order_id, $addressee, $label_type, $deposit_date, $weight, $CN23);

            if ($label->messages->id != 0) {
              $messageStack->add_session($label->messages->messageContent);
              $error_code = $label->messages->id;
              tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHIPPING_LABEL,'action=get_infos&order_id=' . $order_id . '&error_code=' . $error_code));
            } else {
              $email_url_param = 'order_id';
              $qry = "SELECT osh.billing_status_id
                        FROM " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS_HISTORY . " AS osh
                       WHERE osh.orders_id = " . (int)$order_id . "
                    ORDER BY osh.orders_status_history_id
                       LIMIT 1";
              $query = tep_db_query($qry);
              $result = tep_db_fetch_array($query);
              $parcel_number = tep_db_input($label->labelResponse->parcelNumber);
              $comments = str_replace('[TN]', $parcel_number, $comments);
              // send mail
              $qry = "SELECT customers_name, customers_email_address, billing_status, orders_language, date_purchased
                        FROM orders
                       WHERE orders_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'";
              $order_qry = tep_db_query($qry);
              $order_info = tep_db_fetch_array($order_qry);
              $billing_status = $order_info['billing_status'];
              $order_lang = $order_info['orders_language'];
              $scrambled_order_num = randomise_order_num($order_id);
              $languages = tep_get_languages();
              $base_lang = '';
              foreach ($languages as $lang) {
                if ($lang['id'] == $order_lang && ($base_lang == '' || $base_lang == $order_lang)) {
                  $dir = $lang['directory'];
                  $base_lang = $order_lang;
                }
              }
              require_once(DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $dir . '/orders_auto_email.php');
              require(DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'includes/classes/' . FILENAME_TRACKING_MODULE);
              include(DIR_FS_CATALOG_LANGUAGES . $language . '/' . FILENAME_TRACKING_MODULE);
              if (isset($_POST['partial'])){
                $shipping_status = SHIPPING_STATUS_PARTIALLY_SHIPPED;
                $email_comment = EMAIL_TEXT_PARTIALLY_SHIPPED;
                $soon = EMAIL_TEXT_CONTACT_SOON;
              } else {
                $shipping_status = SHIPPING_STATUS_SHIPPED;
                $email_comment = EMAIL_TEXT_SHIPPED;
                $soon = '';
              }
              $tracking = new tracking_module();
              $tracking->suffix = $shipping->suffix;
              $tracking->tracking_id = $parcel_number;
              $tracking->fill_comment();

              $email_comment .= $tracking->shipping_name  . ".\n" . EMAIL_TEXT_RECEPTION . $tracking->delay . "\n" . $soon . EMAIL_TEXT_THX;
              if (!empty($comments)) {
                $email_comment = $comments;
              }

              $email = sprintf(EMAIL_TEXT_ORDER_NUMBER . ' ' . $scrambled_order_num . "\n" .
                               EMAIL_TEXT_DATE_ORDERED . ' ' . email_date_long($order_info['date_purchased'], $order_lang) . "\n\n" .
                               $email_comment . "\n\n" .
                               $tracking->email_add_tracking() . "\n\n" .
                               EMAIL_TEXT_INVOICE_URL . ' ' . tep_catalog_href_link(FILENAME_CATALOG_ACCOUNT_HISTORY_INFO, $email_url_param . '=' . $scrambled_order_num, 'SSL', false) . "\n\n" ) . EMAIL_TEXT_REPLY_TO . "\n";


      // send mail to aide for now
      //$order_info['customers_email_address']


              tep_mail($order_info['customers_name'], $order_info['customers_email_address'], EMAIL_TEXT_SUBJECT, $email, STORE_OWNER, STORE_OWNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
              // start update
              if ($quantity_left != 1) {
                $shipping_status = SHIPPING_STATUS_READY_TO_SHIP;
              }
              $qry = "UPDATE orders
                         SET shipping_status = '" . $shipping_status . "',
                             picked = 0, is_partial = 0,
                             last_modified = NOW()
                       WHERE orders_id ='" . (int)$order_id . "'";
              tep_db_query($qry);
              $qry = "INSERT INTO " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS_HISTORY . "
                                  (orders_id, shipping_status_id, billing_status_id, date_added, customer_notified, comments, tracking_id)
                           VALUES
                                  ('" . (int)$order_id . "', '" . (int)$shipping_status . "', '" . (int)$result['billing_status_id'] . "', now(), 1, '" . tep_db_input($email_comment) . "', '" . tep_db_input($parcel_number . "|" . $shipping->suffix) . "')";
              tep_db_query($qry);
              $qry = "INSERT INTO " . TABLE_BORDEREAU . "
                                  (parcel_number, parcel_type, order_id, customers_name, customers_address, zipcode, city, country_code, weight)
                           VALUES
                                  ('" . tep_db_input($parcel_number) . "', '" . tep_db_input($label_type) . "', '" . tep_db_input($order_id) . "', '" . tep_db_input($addressee['lastName']) . "', '" . tep_db_input($addressee['line2']) . "', '" . tep_db_input($addressee['zipCode']) . "', '" . tep_db_input($addressee['city']) . "', '" . tep_db_input($addressee['countryCode']) . "', '" . tep_db_input($weight) . "')";
              tep_db_query($qry);
              // prep data to print
              $_SESSION['tmp_label_filename'] = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'zpl');
              $handle = fopen($_SESSION['tmp_label_filename'], 'w');
              fwrite($handle, $label->labelResponse->label);
              fclose($handle);
              if (isset($label->labelResponse->cn23)) {
                $_SESSION['tmp_pdf_filename'] = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "pdf");
                $handle = fopen($_SESSION['tmp_pdf_filename'], "w");
                fwrite($handle,$label->labelResponse->cn23);
                fclose($handle);
              }

              if ( $quantity_left > 1) {
                $_SESSION['quantity_needed'] = $quantity_left;
                tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHIPPING_LABEL,'action=get_infos&print=true&order_id=' . $order_id));
              } else {
                tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHIPPING_LABEL,'print=true&order_id=' . $order_id));
              }
            }
          } else {
            $messageStack->add_session(TEXT_ERROR_ALREADY_PROCESSED . '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, 'oID=' . $order_id . '&action=edit') . '"> ' . randomise_order_num($order_id) . '</a>');
            tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHIPPING_LABEL));
          }
        }
        ?>
    <!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html <?php echo HTML_PARAMS; ?>>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo CHARSET; ?>">
        <title><?php echo HEADING_TITLE; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/stylesheet.css">
        <script language="javascript" src="includes/general.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <?php
      if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'get_infos') {
    ?>
        <script src="js/orders.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready( function() {
    <?php
          if (isset($_GET['error_code'])) {
            switch ($_GET['error_code']) {
              case '30221':
                echo '$(\'input[name="addressee\\[mobileNumber\\]"]\').focus();';
            }
          }
    ?>
            $('input[name="addressee\\[firstName\\]"]').attr("id", "cbname");
            $('input[name="addressee[pickupLocationId]"]').keyup(function(){
              let val = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "shipping_label.php?action=relai_lookup&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>",
                data: {
                  "relai_id": val,

                },
                success: function(data) {
                  let obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                  $("input[name='addressee[line2]']").val(obj['entry_street_address']);
                  $("input[name='addressee[zipCode]']").val(obj['entry_postcode']);
                  $("input[name='addressee[city]']").val(obj['entry_city']);
                  if (obj['entry_street_address'].toLowerCase().indexOf('poste') >=0 ) {
                    $("select#label_type option[value='BPR']").prop('selected', true);
                  } else {
                    $("select#label_type option[value='A2P']").prop('selected', true);
                  }
                }
              })
            })
          });
        </script>
    <?php
      }
      if (isset($_GET['print']) && $_GET['print'] == 'true') {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.open('print_shipping_label.php?label=<?php echo $_SESSION['tmp_label_filename']; ?>', '_blank');
    <?php
          if (isset($_SESSION['tmp_pdf_filename'])) {
    ?>
            window.open('print_shipping_label.php?pdf=<?php echo $_SESSION['tmp_pdf_filename']; ?>', '_blank');
            window.open('invoice.php?qty=3&oID=<?php echo $order_id; ?>', '_blank');
    <?php
          }
    ?>
        </script>
    <?php
        }
          if ($action === "get_infos"){
            echo '<link href="includes/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type=" text / css ">';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/datepicker.js"></script>';
          }
    ?>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" >
      <!-- header //-->
      <?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'header.php'); ?>
      <!-- header_eof //-->

      <!-- body //-->
      <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
          <td width="<?php echo BOX_WIDTH; ?>" valign="top"><table border="0" width="<?php echo BOX_WIDTH; ?>" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="columnLeft">
              <!-- left_navigation //-->
              <?php require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'column_left.php'); ?>
              <!-- left_navigation_eof //-->
            </table></td>
            <!-- body_text //-->
            <td width="100%" valign="top"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
              <tr>
                <td class="pageHeading" colspan="2">
                  <?php echo HEADING_TITLE; ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <?php

    function tep_generate_token() {
        $token = sha1(mt_rand());
        $_SESSION['token'] = array($token => 1);
        print_r($_SESSION);
        return $token;
    }

      switch ($action) {
        case 'get_infos':
          echo tep_draw_form('colis', 'shipping_label.php?action=get_label&order_id=' . $order_id, '', 'post');
          print_r($_SESSION);
          $token = tep_generate_token();
          echo tep_draw_hidden_field('token', $token);
          print_r($_SESSION);
    ?>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
    <?php
    ?>
                <label for="weight"><?php echo LABEL_WEIGHT; ?></label>
              </td>
              <td>
    <?php
          echo tep_draw_input_field('weight', '', 'id="weight" autofocus') . '<br>';
    ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="partial"><?php echo LABEL_PARTIAL; ?></label>
              </td>
              <td>
    <?php
          echo tep_draw_checkbox_field('partial', '', $status['is_partial'], "partial") . '<br>';
    ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
          <label for="labels_qty"><?php echo LABEL_NEEDED; ?></label>
              </td>
              <td>
    <?php
          for ($i=1; $i < 9; $i++) {
            $dropdown_values[] = array("id" => $i, "text" => $i);
          }
          $default_labels = $quantity_left - 1;
          echo tep_draw_pull_down_menu('labels_qty', $dropdown_values, $default_labels, 'id="labels_qty"') . '<br>';
          echo tep_draw_hidden_field('order_id', $order_id);
          $date_format = 'class="dateformat-d-sl-m-sl-Y range-low-today" size="10"';
    ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
               <label for="deposit_date"><?php echo LABEL_DEPOSIT_DATE; ?></label>
              </td>
              <td>
    <?php
          echo tep_draw_input_field("deposit_date", $value = '', $parameters = $date_format) . '<br>';
    ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>
               <label for="relai_id"><?php echo LABEL_RELAI_ID; ?></label>
              </td>
              <td>
    <?php
          $addressee = $shipping->get_addressee($order_id);
          $relai_id = '';
          $default_product = 'DOM';
          $CN23_needed = false;
          if (!empty($addressee['address']['pickupLocationId'])) {
            preg_match("#.*(\d{6})\/.+#", $addressee['address']['pickupLocationId'], $matches);
            $relai_id = $matches[1];
            if (strpos(strtolower($addressee['address']['line2']), 'poste') == false) {
              $default_product = 'A2P';
            } else {
              $default_product = 'BPR';
            }
          } else if ($addressee['address']['countryCode'] == 'FD') {
            $CN23_needed = true;
            $addressee['address']['countryCode'] = 'FR';
            $default_product = 'COM';
          }
          unset($addressee['address']['pickupLocationId']);
          echo tep_draw_input_field("addressee[pickupLocationId]", $relai_id) . '<br>';
          foreach ($addressee['address'] as $field => $value) {
            if ($field == 'orders_language') continue;
    ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="<?php echo $field ?>"><?php echo constant(LABEL_ . strtoupper($field)); ?></label>
              </td>
              <td>
    <?php
            echo tep_draw_input_field("addressee[" . $field . "]", $value, 'style="width: 300px"') . '<br>';
    ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
    <?php
          }
    ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="comment"><?php echo LABEL_COMMENT; ?></label>
              </td>
              <td>
    <?php
                $languages = tep_get_languages();
                foreach ($languages as $lang) {
                  if ($lang['id'] == $addressee['address']['orders_language']) {
                    echo tep_draw_hidden_field('cblang', $lang['code'], 'id="cblang"');
                    $order_language = $lang['code'];
                  }
                }
                echo tep_draw_hidden_field('cbshipping', $module, 'id="cbshipping"');
                echo tep_draw_hidden_field('cborder', $order_num, 'id="cborder"');
                echo tep_draw_hidden_field('cbnotify', '', 'id="cbnotify" checked="checked"');
                echo tep_draw_textarea_field('comments', 'virtual', '60', '5');
                // TODO create a premier second ... array
                if ($orders_language == 'en') {
                  $parcel_dropdown_options = array(array('id' => '1', 'text' => 'first'),
                                                   array('id' => '2', 'text' => 'second'),
                                                   array('id' => '3', 'text' => 'third'),
                                                   array('id' => '4', 'text' => 'fourth'),
                                                   array('id' => '5', 'text' => 'fith'));
                } else {
                  $parcel_dropdown_options = array(array('id' => '1', 'text' => 'premier'),
                                                   array('id' => '2', 'text' => 'deuxi&egrave;me'),
                                                   array('id' => '3', 'text' => 'troisi&egrave;me'),
                                                   array('id' => '4', 'text' => 'quatri&egrave;me'),
                                                   array('id' => '5', 'text' => 'cinqui&egrave;me'));
                }
    ?>
              <br>
    <?php
              echo tep_draw_pull_down_menu('parcel_number', $parcel_dropdown_options, '', 'id="parcel_number"');
    ?>
              <input type="button" value="nd track nb" onclick="preloadnewshippingnumbercomment('Tatiana', true);">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="delivery_comment"><?php echo LABEL_DELIVERY_COMMENT; ?></label>
              </td>
              <td>
    <?php
              $delivery_comment = '';
              $qry = "SELECT comments
                        FROM orders_status_history
                       WHERE orders_id = '" . $order_id . "'
                         AND packing_slip = 1";
              $query = tep_db_query($qry);
              while ($rslt = tep_db_fetch_array($query)) {
                $delivery_comment .= $rslt['comments'] . "\n";
              }
              echo tep_draw_textarea_field('addressee[delivery_comment]', 'virtual', '60', '5', $delivery_comment);
    ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
    <?php
          if ($shipping->need_CN23($addressee['address']['countryCode']) || $CN23_needed) {
            $dropdown_none = array('id' => '', 'text' => TEXT_NONE);
            $origin_country_array = array_merge(array($dropdown_none), tep_get_countries('', null, true));
            $qry = "SELECT op.products_id, op.products_name AS description, op.products_quantity AS quantity, psl.weight AS weight, ROUND(op.products_price, 2) AS value, p.origin_country_id,
                        (SELECT REPLACE(ROUND(ot.value, 2), '.', '')
                           FROM orders_total AS ot
                          WHERE ot.orders_id = '" . tep_db_input($order_id) . "'
                            AND ot.class = 'ot_shipping') AS totalAmount
                      FROM orders_products AS op
                 LEFT JOIN products AS p
                        ON op.products_id = p.products_id
                 LEFT JOIN products_stock_location AS psl
                        ON p.products_id = psl.products_id
                       AND (psl.option_id IN (SELECT opa.products_options_values_id
                                               FROM orders_products_attributes AS opa
                                              WHERE opa.orders_id = '" . tep_db_input($order_id) . "'
                                                AND op.orders_products_id = opa.orders_products_id)
                        OR psl.option_id IS NULL)
                     WHERE op.orders_id = '" . tep_db_input($order_id) . "'";
            $query = tep_db_query($qry);
            echo '<tr><td><label for="cn23_categories">' . TEXT_LABEL_CN23_CATEGORIES .  '</td>';
            $CN23_categories_array = $shipping->get_CN23_categories();
            $CN23_product_families_array = $shipping->get_CN23_product_families();
            echo '<td>' . tep_draw_pull_down_menu('CN23[category]', $CN23_categories_array, 3) . '</td></tr>';

            echo '<tr><td colspan=2><table>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>' . TABLE_HEADING_DESCRIPTION . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . TABLE_HEADING_QUANTITY . '</th>';
            echo '<th id="weight_title">' . TABLE_HEADING_WEIGHT . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . TABLE_HEADING_VALUE . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . TABLE_HEADING_FAMILY . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . TABLE_HEADING_ORIGIN_COUNTRY . '</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
            while ($result = tep_db_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo tep_draw_hidden_field('CN23[totalAmount]', $result['totalAmount']);
              echo '<tr>';
              echo '<td>' . tep_draw_input_field('CN23[' . $result['products_id'] . '][description]', $result['description']) . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . tep_draw_input_field('CN23[' . $result['products_id'] . '][quantity]', $result['quantity']) . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . tep_draw_input_field('CN23[' . $result['products_id'] . '][weight]', $result['weight'], 'class="js_weight"') . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . tep_draw_input_field('CN23[' . $result['products_id'] . '][value]', $result['value']) . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . tep_draw_pull_down_menu('CN23[' . $result['products_id'] . '][hsCode]', $CN23_product_families_array) . '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . tep_draw_pull_down_menu('CN23[' . $result['products_id'] . '][originCountry]', $origin_country_array, $result['origin_country_id']) . '</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table></td></tr>';
          }
    ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
    <?php
          echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_SHIPPING_LABEL) . '">' . tep_css_button(BUTTON_BACK, false) . '</a>';
          echo tep_css_button(BUTTON_SUBMIT, true);
          break;
        case 'get_label':
          //   echo '<div class="hidden">' . $label . '</div>';
          // }
        break;
        default:
          echo tep_draw_form('colis', 'shipping_label.php?action=get_infos', '', 'post');
    ?>
            <label for="order_num"><?php echo LABEL_ORDER; ?></label>
    <?php
          echo tep_draw_input_field('order_num', '', 'id="order_num" autofocus');
          echo tep_css_button(BUTTON_SUBMIT, true);
        break;
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's the `print_r` code just outside the function?

Comment: same as inside  `print_r($_SESSION); `

Comment: It's showing same output for both cases. Can you show full code?

Comment: Your example output is different, but you said its the same debugging logic. Please share accurate examples of what you're doing =)

Comment: it's not same output, in one case token is an array with a token as the key and a value 1, in the other one, it's only the token key with the token inside. i'll  upload the full code in a minute

Comment: @RobbieAverill that's exactly my problem, same debugging logic, but different output, just by assigning or not the result of the function to a variable